# Selected Value of select tag does not change outside switch in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, ng-switch

If I put a select tag inside ng-switch then two way binding does not work for select tag ng-model outside ng-switch.

Please refer following code

```
<div ng-switch on="OutputStep">
                <div ng-switch-when="0">
                   Switch Step One
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-when="1">
                     Switch Step Two<br/>
                       <select ng-model="SelectedReviewOption" ng-options="review as review.DisplayValue for review in ReviewOptions">
                       </select>
                       Selected Value : {{SelectedReviewOption.DisplayValue}}             
                </div>                        
</div>
<button ng-click="OutputStep = '0'" ng-disabled="OutputStep == '0'">
Back
</button>
<button ng-click="OutputStep = '1'" ng-disabled="OutputStep == '1'">
Next
</button>
Selected Value Outside Switch : {{SelectedReviewOption.DisplayValue}}
```

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shashanktriv/82s7xatt/), click Next button to view 2nd switch page. Change value in select tag. Observe that changed value cannot be displayed outside switch –

Comment: In your jsfiddle. there is nothing concrete to see.. please create the use case . thanks

Comment: here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shashanktriv/cobc0u3p/5/ ... In this, click Next button to view 2nd switch page. Change value in select tag. Observe that changed value cannot be displayed outside switch

Comment: Please extract the relevant code from jsfiddle and post it in the question. If the jsfiddle link changed or became invalid your question would not have any meaning to someone else.

Comment: You've indented the line with your link on in order to allow this post. That's not what the validation warning meant. If you link out to code you must include code in your question/answer for the reason @NewDev stated.

Comment: To reiterate what @lukkea said please don't use "tricks" to "sidestep" the quality filter, it's there for a reason. Deliberately avoiding it without fixing the actual problem looks pretty bad to moderators.

Comment: I tried to resolve it, hope it looks better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $parent.var_name in ng model , as ng switch creates it seperate scope , and the variable will be restricted to it if its not explicitly defined outside the scope by ng-init or something(in the controller)

Answer (score 1):

Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. So, use

```
<input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1"> rather than 
<input type="text" ng-model="prop1">
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/cobc0u3p/7/)

[understanding scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Answer (score 0):

Here is now..
You need to use $parent to get to parent scope, outside the switch block

```
$parent.SelectedReviewOption
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cobc0u3p/6/